# How to directly divide two Duration objects in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, math, duration

In Dart, let's say you have:

```
Duration duration01 = Duration(milliseconds: 10000);
Duration duration02 = Duration(milliseconds: 100);
```

I know that while add or subtract seems to work, doing:

```
double result = duration01 / duration02;
```

does not work.

And *I know how to do it using basic math by unwrapping and re-wrapping the duration objects*... but is there a way to do it directly like I am attempting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dividing one `Duration` by another is not something that most people need to do, so there's no built-in way to do it.

You always can convert the `Duration` objects to microseconds and then perform arithmetic.  Since `Duration` does not already have `operator /`, you can add one as an extension method to make it more convenient:

```dart
extension DurationDivision on Duration {
  double operator / (Duration other) =>
      inMicroseconds / other.inMicroseconds;
}

void main() {
  Duration duration01 = Duration(milliseconds: 10000);
  Duration duration02 = Duration(milliseconds: 100);
  print(duration01 / duration02); // Prints: 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the functions provided by the `Duration` object.

try this code:

```
Duration duration01 = Duration(milliseconds: 10000);
  Duration duration02 = Duration(milliseconds: 100);

  Duration result = Duration(
    milliseconds: duration01.inMilliseconds ~/ duration02.inMilliseconds,
  );
```

You can also use methods other than `Duration.inMilliseconds` to get the duration object in any form you want, some of them are:

- inDays
- inHours
- inMicroseconds
- inMinutes
- inSeconds